# wxPython src rpm build fails

Tags: centos, wxpython, rpm, centos6, rpmbuild

I wanted to install `wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.src.rpm` on my Centos6 box with the src rpm provided here http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/

I did this as root:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.src.rpm
```

and in the end I have :

```
running install_egg_info
Writing /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wxPython-2.8.12.1-py2.6.egg-info
warning: wx_install: path file '/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode.pth' not created
running build_ext
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6
creating /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
copying build-gtk2.unicode/lib/wxversion.py -> /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
byte-compiling /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wxversion.py to wxversion.pyc
running install_data
copying src/wx.pth -> /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
running install_egg_info
Writing /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wxPython_common-2.8.12.1-py2.6.egg-info
+ rm /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib/wxPython-2.8.12.1-gtk2-unicode/bin/wx-config
+ strip '/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib*/python2.4/site-packages/wx-2.8*-gtk2-unicode/wx/*.so'
strip: '/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.x86_64/usr/lib*/python2.4/site-packages/wx-2.8*-gtk2-unicode/wx/*.so': No such file
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.yji3iJ (%install)


RPM build errors:
    user robind does not exist - using root
    group robind does not exist - using root
    user robind does not exist - using root
    group robind does not exist - using root
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.yji3iJ (%install)
```

Any solutions?

I use python version 2.6.6 on 64 bit CentOS release 6.5

Answer (score 1):

Something appears to be broken in the spec file in that SRPM.

Notice how the path in the error is talking about `python2.4`? And how the earlier paths (e.g. in the copying lines) correctly use `python2.6`?

Something in the spec file isn't getting the path from the correct place somehow.

You'll have to look at the spec file to see if you can figure it out or file a bug with the wxpython people and see what they say.

You could also check for patches in distribution packages to see if any of them have worked around this issue there.

Comment: I am trying to find this but: how to extract spec from .src.rpm?

Comment: `mkdir wxpython-extract; cd wxpython-extract; rpm2cpio ../wxPython2.8-2.8.12.1-1.src.rpm | cpio -id` will extract it all locally. You could also always just install the SRPM which would puts its files into the RPM build/spec file locations as specified by your rpm configuration (I believe).